# Can someone explain to me the parameters of a lognormal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I'm doing some reading and this is the definition I got from DeGroot's book:
[image]

Does that mean the parameters are the same?  For example, assume X is lognormally distributed and Y is normally distributed where Y = log(X).  Is this saying that X and Y have the same mean and SDs even though they are different shaped distributions?  If not, what distribution is μ and σ referring to?

In other words, if someone says X is lognormally distributed with mean μ and SD σ, do I need to do any conversion so that the mean and SD are in normal terms?

Comment: Do not confuse *parameters* of a distribution family with *moments.*  Although $\mu,\sigma$ parameterize the Lognormal distributions, they are not their means or standard deviations.

Comment: They have the same parameters, but they don't have the same mean or the same standard deviation. The two parameters, $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ that are the mean and standard deviation of $\log X,$ are not the mean and standard deviation of $X.$ But the mean and standard deviation of $X$ are functions of $\mu$ and $\sigma. \qquad$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> assume X is lognormally distributed and Y is normally distributed where Y = log(X)

This is where you are confused. You don't make assumptions on two distributions, one of which just happens to be the log of the other.

Instead, you start with a distribution $X$. Then you consider $\log X$. If $\log X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, *then* we say that the original distribution $X$ is *[lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$*.

(And then the mean of $X$ is $\exp\left(\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$, for instance, so the parameters are certainly not the same. This is also why it is better to speak of the "parameters" of a lognormal, rather than of the "mean and SD" - because it's very easy to get confused whether these refer to the actual mean or the log-mean, same for SD.)

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying.  So generally when people provide the parameters, such as μ and σ, that refers to the distribution of Y or log(X).  To get the mean of the lognormal distribution requires a conversion.

Comment: Nice answer! I was just a few seconds late in posting mine. 

Comment: But the parameters are the same. Then mean and the standard deviation and many other things are the same, but those two parameters are the same.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: yes, the parameters are the same, by definition. I just wince a bit every time someone calls $\mu$ the "mean parameter of the lognormal", because it's only the log-mean, and it's so easy to confuse them.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia has a nice article on log-normal distributions: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution. The article reveals that the log-normally distributed X and the normally distributed log(X) have different means and standard deviations.

If X follows a log-normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then $\mu$ and $\sigma$ represent the mean and standard deviation of the distribution of log(X), which is normal. In other words, the mean and standard deviation of the normally distributed log(X) are:

Mean of $\log(X)=\mu$

SD of $\log(X) = \sigma$

The mean and standard deviation of the log-normally distributed X are as follows:

Mean of X = $\exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)$

SD of X = $\sqrt{\left[\exp\left(\sigma^2\right) - 1\right] \cdot \exp(2\mu + \sigma^2)}$

Comment: Isabella Ghement's answer is good.. Just wanted to point out that in that answer, SD of X has a typo. exp[^2−1] should be (exp[^2]−1). Was doing Monte Carlo sampling to verify the mean and SD of a log-normal distribution and my SD did not match with the above expression. Verified the wiki page linked and noted the typo. PS: Actually wanted to add a comment to @Isabella Ghement answer but don't have necessary credentials to do that. Adding a new answer instead.